# Unable to Display SQLIte query results in browser

Tags: php, pdo, sqlite

I am trying to display the results of a SQLite query on browser using php.

I connected to the database using

> $conn = new PDO('sqlite:test.db');

Below is my query

> $query = $conn->query("SELECT * FROM main");

Below is my fetch function

> $row = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

I get the output when I run it from my terminal using

> php myscript.php

But when I try to open the same script from browser, its showing empty screen as it is not getting any response from server.

Can anybody help me debugging it ?

Please post if you have any working script for the same. I am out of due to submit my college project.

Comment: Turn on [`error_reporting`](http://php.net/manual/en/language.errors.basics.php), check the `php_errors` log.

Comment: I am sorry, I was busy with my project. I tried it using conventional sqlite3 API. It worked for me. As I am nearing my due date, I will work on PDO and let you know the solution soon. Thanks for spending your time for me.